# Mathematical expression (string) to number in Java

Tags: java, parsing, formula, evaluate, mathematical-expressions

I'm trying to find something like [Java Embedding Plugin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Embedding_Plugin) (JEP) that can evaluate a mathematical formula (string) and give back the answer.

But it should also calculate a variable, for example: (25+36+x)*2 = 25 should give: x = -11

A little like http://www.wolframalpha.com/, but it shouldn't be that versatile, and it should work off-line.

Open source is preferred.

I need it for my little calculator project, http://sourceforge.net/projects/calex/.

Comment: This shouldn't be closed, since he wants to solve an equation and is not looking for something like javascripts eval().

Comment: Unless you're limiting yourself to a very few forms of equation (say linear up to quartic), then this would be a major project. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_computer_algebra_systems has a few Java ones.

Answer (score 3):

This is called `Arithmetic evaluation`. One of the easiest way to implement this is using Edsger Dijkstra [Shunting-yard_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

> The shunting-yard algorithm is a
> method for parsing mathematical
> equations specified in infix notation.
> It can be used to produce output in
> Reverse Polish notation (RPN) or as an
> abstract syntax tree (AST). The
> algorithm was invented by Edsger
> Dijkstra and named the "shunting yard"
> algorithm because its operation
> resembles that of a railroad shunting
> yard. Like the evaluation of RPN, the
> shunting yard algorithm is
> stack-based. Infix expressions are the
> form of mathematical notation most
> people are used to, for instance 3+4
> or 3+4*(2−1). For the conversion there
> are two text variables (strings), the
> input and the output. There is also a
> stack that holds operators not yet
> added to the output queue. To convert,
> the program reads each symbol in order
> and does something based on that
> symbol.

But I have seen exact solution what you are looking for on some stackoverflow user blog, but I can't remember the address (it was like 'code monkeyism'). It was lightweight class, that you could use in applets (you could also define constants and reset values).

**Edit:** Found it: http://tech.dolhub.com/Code/MathEval

> A Linear-Recursive Math Evaluator
>
> This math expression evaluator was born out of a need to have a small-footprint and efficient solution which could evaluate arbitrary expressions reasonably efficiently without requiring pre-compilation. I needed something which would do basic math with variables, expressions like: "Top+2", "Bottom-2" and "(Right+1-Left)/2".
>
> Research on the Internet turned up a number of fairly good solutions, all of which revolved around creating parse trees (which makes sense). The problem was - they were all rather bulky, and I couldn't afford to add 100K to my applet size just for math. So I started wondering about a linear recursive solution to the problem. The end result is an acceptably performing single class with no external dependencies, weighing in under 10 KiB.

Comment: Except my evaluator won't *solve* equations like the example in the question where the variable is the unknown.  It could only take various values of x using trial and error and evaluate `(25+36+x)*2` until the answer given is 25.

Comment: You would have to manipulate the equation to get x by itself on one side of the equals: I think `(25+36+x)*2=25`  =>  `x=25/2-(25+36)`, if I recall my math correctly, evaluates (correctly) to -48.5, not -11.

Comment: Well, yes. Wolfram alpha uses some fancy AI to fix invalid input, and `(25 + 36 + x)*2 = 25` becomes `Solve[(25 + 36 + x)*2 == 25, x]`, so I assumed, that he needs to write a 'linear systems solver' or do it manually.

Comment: wow, thx for the fast reply, i'll check it out and let you know what algebra_system i used :)

Answer (score 0):

I released an expression evaluator based on [Dijkstra's Shunting Yard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) algorithm, under the terms of the [Apache License 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html):

http://projects.congrace.de/exp4j/index.html

Comment: looks nice :), i might add it to my project. although for a calculator the bootspeed of java is rather slow. maybe i need to revise it and start over in c++.